# LaTeX math overline/overrightarrow vertical alignment?

Tags: latex, equation

When I use the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\overline{d} \overline{q}
\end{equation}
```

the overlines are misaligned, with the line on the q being lower than the line on the d. The same thing happens with **\overrightarrow**.  Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\vphantom could fix it:

```
\begin{equation}
\overline{d} \overline{q\vphantom{d}}
\end{equation}
```

\vphantom inserts vertical space according to the height of its argument and has zero width.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
\begin{equation}
\overline{\strut d} \overline{q \strut}
\end{equation}
```